# Enviar un parametro de un metodo dentro de una clase a otra clase C#

Tags: c#

Hola amigos quiero enviar un parametro de un metodo de una clase a otra clase pero no se como hacerlo

```js
public void Clase1(String parametro){

  String parame = parametro//=> parame => quiero enviar a una clase para que lo puedan usar varios metodos
}
```

Aca es el metodo que recibe ese parametro

```js
public void Clase2(){
 
  //=> aca en donde recibe el parame de la Clase1

}
```

Comment: Está media confusa la redaccion, no se entiende que es lo que queres hacer. Además usas la palabra "Clase", pero en realidad Clase1 y Clase2 en tu ejemplo son métodos, no clases.

Answer (score 1):

yo lo que normalmente hago es hacer uso de los constructores con POO asi:

```
  public void Clase1(String parametro){

       String parame = parametro//=> parame => quiero enviar a una clase para que lo 
       puedan usar varios metodos
       clase2 objC2=new Clase2(parame);
    }

public void Clase2(){
 String parame;
 Clase2(String parame){
 this.parame=parame;
 }
```

Lo que hace es que instancias el objeto de la **clase2** en la **Clase1** y le envias a su contructor (si no sabes sobre constructor consulta en google constructores y constructores sobrecargados), y **this.parame** lo que hace es que llama a la variable de la clase y se la asigna la que le mandan.

Espero te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que necesitas es instansear tu clase2 en tu metodo de la clase1
pero lo que veo es que le indicas tu parametro del metodo1 al metodo2 (clase2)
usas clases como nombres en metodos, deberias utilizar el nombre del metodo, ya que es confuso.
lo que podrias hacer es instansear tu clase Clase2 dentro de tu metodo2

```
public class Clase1{

private void metodo1(string parametro){
   // creas una instansea de tu clase 2 y con eso tienes acceso a las propiedades de la clase 2 y simplemente le seteas el parametro..

   Clase2 cl2 = new Clase2();
   cl2.Parametro = parametro;
}

}


public class Clase2{
     string _parametro;

     public string Parametro{
         get
            {
                return _parametro;
            }

            set
            {
                _parametro= value;
            }
     }

    private void metodo2(){
        // usas la variable _parametro en tu metodo de la clase 2
         Console.WriteLine(_parametro);
    }
}
```

Otra forma seria que indiques como publico tu metodo2 de la clase 2, y le pases como parametro lo que recibes en tu metodo1,

```
Clase2 cl2 = new Clase2();
cl2.metodo2(parametro);


// clase2
public void metodo2(string param){
}
```

Espero haberte ayudado. saludos

Comment: Y que pasa si mi metodo es static, osea que sea private static void metodo2()

Comment: @Alex Si tienes la restricción `private`, no podrás acceder a ese método desde otra clase, debes tener en cuenta eso. En cuanto a si el método es `static`, no hace falta crear una instancia de la **clase2**.. sólo debes llamarlo así: `clase2.metodo2();`

Comment: Especificalo amigo, agrega mas informacion, para que la respuesta sea concreta. debes indicar tu clase como static.  paea llamarlo unicamente harias uso de *clase2.metodo2()* sin necesidad de instansear la clase

Answer (score 0):

Primero que todo, como bien te menciona el colega **ZottoSL**, lo que estas mencionando como *Clases* en realidad son *Métodos*. Una clase no es más que un contenedor que posee **N** métodos o funciones.

Aclaro esto, para realizar lo que deseas debes llamar a **Clase2** dentro de **Clase1** y pasar como parámetro a *Clase2*, el que recibe *Clase1*.

```
public class Vehiculo
{
   public void Atributos(string color)
   {
      Auto auto = new Auto();
      auto.SetColor(color);
   }
}

public class Auto
{
   private string color { get; set }

   public void SetColor(string color)
   { 
      this.color = color;
   }
}
```

Ahora bien, si tu método2 no recibe parámetros (como es en este caso), debes setear la propiedad directamente.

```
public class Vehiculo
{
   public void Atributos(string color)
   {
      Auto auto = new Auto();
      auto.color = color;
   }
}

public class Auto
{
   public string color { get; set }
}
```

Nos comentas como te va =)